# How to import external APIs in Shopify liquid?

Tags: json, api, shopify, liquid, shopify-api

I am currently building a Shopify store.

A key aspect is providing Personalized Recommendations on the Shopify store.
For this, we are not looking at using the inbuilt Shopify recommendations - rather through the recommendation APIs from our in-house ML-based Recommendation System.

While I have gone through how Shopify creates the Recommendation carousell, how can I plug in our own APIs to generate the recommendations instead?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.